# Increasing space between strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel to format a string in cell and need to increase the single space to two spaces. If my text string is `JOHN DOE`, I need to increase the single space to 2 to show the result as `JOHN  DOE`. How can I do this in excel? Pls note my text string varies in length.

Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+H not doing this for you?

Comment: What have you tried? What if string contains 2 spaces between two words (is this a possible case)?

Comment: Yes possible, however I would have already scrubbed the data string to make it single space in a step before this. Additional space is the last step. Thanks. Ctrl+H did not help

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want any number of spaces replaced with 2 spaces (e.g. 1,3,4,5...), then try

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","  ")
```